# Using argv to pass variable in C

Tags: c, while-loop, argv

I am coding in C this semester for a microprocessing class. Our first small assignment is to calculate the summation from i=0 to a user defined value N of the function (1/(1+i^2)). I want to take one of the argument variables on the command line to pass as the value of N so the user can execute my program from the command line (this is a requirement from my prof). Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv)
{
    int i = 0;
    float sum = 0;

    while (argv[1] >= i)
        { 
        sum += 1/(1+pow(i,2));
        i++;
        }
    printf("%f",sum);
    printf("%c",argv[-1]);
    getchar();
}
```

This code is saved as microp.c, I am compiling the code using gcc in the terminal. My terminal commands are as follows:

```
$ gcc microp.c -o microp -lm 
$ ./microp 3
```

I am using the argument 3 as the value N (the upper limit of my summation). My program runs without compiling errors but does not give the correct result. The code gives me the correct answer when I simply give N a value within the code. I suspect its because of the way I'm using argv. Any suggestions?

Comment: `argv[1]` --> `atoi(argv[1])`. Also `argv[-1]` is UB.

Comment: `argv` is a list of *strings*.  You would need to convert those string values into numeric values before you can use them like you're trying to in the above code.

Comment: That's not how command line arguments work. Try a simpler program first until you're comfortable with them.

Comment: `char *argv` Zzzztttt. Try `char* argv[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, i would replace the 'while' with a 'for', so as to make the code more readable for the purpose:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv)
{
    int i = 0;
    float sum = 0;

    for (i=0;i<=argv[1];i++)
    { 
        sum += 1/(1+pow(i,2));
    }
    printf("%f",sum);
    printf("%c",argv[-1]); //this over here, what is it for?
    getchar();
}
```

In second place, I would remove the second printf statement, or at least add a line break, I dont really know what argv[-1] is supposed to be, since it looks out of bounds

```
printf("%f \n ",sum);
//printf("%c \n ",argv[-1]);
```

---

### This is how 'argc' 'argv' works...

**argc** stands for *argument count*, its basically the a positive integer that states the size of **argv**, which stands for *argument values*

So, your argv[] domain will go from 0 -> (argc-1)
Bear in mind that the mere execution of the program itself counts as an argument, argv[0]...
So calling   ***./microp 3***   would result in an argv array with this content:

```
["./microp", "3"]
```

### **IMPORTANT**

Something I've just realized is that *argv* takes only strings as members, so when you pass the "3" as a parameter, your program actually takes its ASCII value, so try doing some validation before, or just cast it

```
 int main(int argc, char *argv)
{
    int i = 0;
    float sum = 0;
    argv[1]=atoi(argv[1]); //this is just an example of string to int conversion
...
```

If you have further trouble, please let me know, good luck =)

Comment: if you pass a number with more than one digit, it should crash, because the ASCII value is taken only for individual characters, thats another reason why you should convert it

Comment: The prototype for `main` is `int main(int argc, char* argv[])`. You could write `char** argv`. But `char* argv` is just not going to work.

Comment: So I have used @Mr.Robot suggestions to convert the type but atoi() seems to throw me an error:
`warning: passing argument 1 of ‘atoi’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  N = atoi(argv[1]);`
           ^
Also:
`/usr/include/stdlib.h:147:12: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘char’
 extern int atoi (const char *__nptr)`

I tried to look up the difference between char and const but I still don't understand why the type conversion doesn't work

Comment: OK! I got it. using the Mr.Robot suggestions and then finally noticing what @John3136 had pointed out. The error was from only putting *argv instead of *argv[] in the parameters of main. Zzztttt indeed.